# ASPX page to show multiple records from SQL table (DetailsView approach)

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

Scenario : In Page1.aspx, user submits zipcode & City and hits enter. I then pass the control to Page2.aspx with zipcode & City.

Here in page2, I will query from a table matching the zipcode & City. If found, I will get 1 to n records.

Now I need to display records in the below fashion.

---

Customer Name  : Customer1

Customer Phone : 201201201

Customer City  : NewCity

---

Customer Name  : Customer2

Customer Phone : 303013010

Customer City  : OldCity

---

Customer Name  : Customer3

Customer Phone : 45646466

Customer City  : CurrentCity

---

Each record above is two columns with first column as header and second the value. I would like to show upto 8 customers (above I have shown 3 customers) in a page and then put the page numbering. Clicking on next page, shows the next set of 8 records.

Please suggest the best control. I thought of DetailsView but do not know if I can show up to 8 occurrences in one page using Detailsview.

Please suggest or any other alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is example  how to display the results using repeater control....

ASP.NET Repeater used with the AlternatingItemTemplate, SeparatorTemplate, HeaderTemplate and FooterTemplates as well as the ItemTemplate.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="NewsListRepeater" runat="server">

 <HeaderTemplate>Funky Title<br /><br /></HeaderTemplate>

  <ItemTemplate>
     <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SpecialNumber") %><br />
     <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SpecialLetters") %><br />
  </ItemTemplate>

  <SeparatorTemplate>
     ------<br />
  </SeparatorTemplate>

 <AlternatingItemTemplate>
     <i><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SpecialNumber") %></i><br />
    <i><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SpecialLetters") %></i><br /> 
  </AlternatingItemTemplate>

  <FooterTemplate><br />End of the funky stuff</FooterTemplate>
```

In the code behind file, the following code is used to create a DataTable and then create some simple data to put into the DataTable just for demonstration purposes, which we then bind to the Repeater.  In the real world you'll be binding your Repeater to the results of a database call or maybe even an XML file.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // create a datatable
   DataTable newsDataTable = new DataTable();

   // add some columns to our datatable
   newsDataTable.Columns.Add("SpecialNumber");
   newsDataTable.Columns.Add("SpecialLetters");

   // create some rows in our data
   string _letters = "ABCDE";
  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
  {
    DataRow newsDataRow = newsDataTable.NewRow();
    newsDataRow["SpecialNumber"] = i;
    newsDataRow["SpecialLetters"] = _letters.Substring(5 -i);
    newsDataTable.Rows.Add(newsDataRow);
  }

  // bind our datatable to our repeater
   NewsListRepeater.DataSource = newsDataTable;
  NewsListRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

and the out put is like this ....

```
Funky Title

1
E
------
2
DE
------
3
CDE
------
4
BCDE
------
5
ABCDE

End of the funky stuff
```

I hope it will helps you....

Answer (score 1):

You can use any templated databound control for this like DataList or DataRepeater.

Try to add it to the page and from right click select Edit item template command. Then you can add all controls you need like labels in your case.

Comment: Are there any examples that are good to share? I will also check.